# PDFLaTeXify, PDFTeXify, Texify, and all other -ify options stopped working in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

I'm working on creating a C.V/Resume in LaTeX and therefore needed to switch to another compiling engine, and I was also fiddling around with using bibtex or biber to parse the bibliography and create an inline bibliography. However, at some point since yesterday WinEdt completely broke and won't compile with the -ify options (e.g. running multiple times, including building bibliography). I'm stumped as I cannot find any error message, and even the MWE without any bibliography below fails.

I looked at the .blg file and it seems that bibtex 0.99d is run, also manually starting bibtex runs OK. It seems to be the 2nd run of the tex compilation that fails. I have reset WinEdt's execution modes to default, I've reinstalled WinEdt and MiKTeX 2.9, all to no avail. Both bibtex and biber commands work from the command line so the paths are ok.

So my main question is what are other points or files I can look into to see what/where the error is?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\begin{document}

MWE

\end{document}
```

Comment: Start a command line and try out texify there.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, TeXiFy from the command line line works just fine... TeXiFy from WinEdt results in a "latex.EXE has stopped working" error message, but not much more information than that...

Comment: I have a similar problem these days with plain compilers: they and the log files  stop without a word and no page is produced, as soon as there's a missing package, instead of stopping with the usual error messages.

Comment: I tried out your example in winedt Build: 20150731  (v. 9.1) - 64-bit and had no problems. But texify doesn't call biber, only bibtex.

Comment: Dear Ulrike, thank you for testing my MWE, this proves to me that the issue is with my installation. However, I have no clue how to continue debugging to get an idea of the root cause. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have just completely uninstalled WinEdt 9.1 and MikTex 2.9, removed all folders from the AppData user dir, and opted for thorough uninstall of MikTex.

Comment: On that basis, 'unclear'.